# Usando Animações num Carousel

Tags: javascript

Estou fazendo um serviço no qual o cliente deseja um Carousel que tenha animaçoes num slide em video quando o mesmo está visivel. O problema é que o codigo que eu montei apenas faz a animação desejada quando o usuario clicar numa das setas do carousel, e não quando o slide estiver visivel. Também com esse meu codigo tá tendo muitos bugs

JS do Carousel:

```
  $('.btn-tooltip').tooltip();
$('.label-tooltip').tooltip();
$('.pick-class-label').click(function(){
    var new_class = $(this).attr('new-class');
    var old_class = $('#display-buttons').attr('data-class');
    var display_div = $('#display-buttons');
    if(display_div.length) {
    var display_buttons = display_div.find('.btn');
    display_buttons.removeClass(old_class);
    display_buttons.addClass(new_class);
    display_div.attr('data-class', new_class);
    }
});
$( "#slider-range" ).slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 500,
    values: [ 75, 300 ],
});
$( "#slider-default" ).slider({
        value: 70,
        orientation: "horizontal",
        range: "min",
        animate: true
});
$('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: 4000000
});
demo.initSharingButtons();

$('video').on('play', function (e) {
$(".carousel").carousel('pause');
});
$('video').on('stop pause ended', function (e) {
$(".carousel").carousel();
});
```

HTML:

```
 <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="assets/img/1_cchbhv0w-RLQQdRYD1zGHA.jpeg" alt="Awesome Image">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="assets/img/caro2.jpg" alt="Awesome Image">
    </div>
    <div class="item HavokVideo img-wrapper">
      <!-- width="1920" height="1080" -->
      <video  autoplay muted width="1920" height="1080" loop>
        <source src="assets/img/video1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
      <div class="overlap-text film-img ">
        <h2 id="text-overlaping"><img src="assets/img/film.png" width="600" height="600" id="mega"></h2>
        <h2 id="videot">Essential CG: O Inicio do seu futuro</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="img-overlay col-md-2 btn-fix">
        <a href="essentials.html" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-success btn-fill" role="button">Saiba Mais</a>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="assets/img/zbrush.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control megabtn" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="fa fa-angle-left"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control megabtn" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
    <span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Script que eu criei pra a animação ocorrer toda vez que o usuario ir pro slide.

```
 var drop = 0;

  $("#mega").hide();
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".megabtn").click(function(){
      if (drop == 1) {
        $("#mega").show(2500);
        drop--;
      } else {
        $("#mega").hide(1000);
        drop++;
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

cria um `setInterval()` chamando a mesma função executada quando clica na seta:

```
function slide(drop){
    if (drop == 1) {
        $("#mega").show(2500);
        drop--;
     } else {
        $("#mega").hide(1000);
        drop++;
    }
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        slide(drop);
    },1000);//1000 milisegundos, representam 1 segundo
}
```

Assim, quando a pagina carregar, esse `setInterval()` vai rodar a cada 1 segundo

Comment: Acho que você não entendeu, eu preciso que se crie algo que faça .carousel('pause') quando o carousel estiver no slide do video.

Comment: Usando isso a animação que deveria ocorrer deixa de acontecer.

Comment: deve ser por causa do tempo do `setInterval()`, quanto ao pause que você disse eu acho que não compreendi, no slide do vídeo o carousel deve parar, isso?

Comment: Exatamente, ao chegar no slide do video eu quero que o carousel pare e animação ocorra. Já fiz a animação ocorrer usando o codigo que define o slide como impar e faz a animação ocorrer em todos os slides que forem impars, porém ela ta bugando.

Comment: O principal mesmo é que no slide do video o carousel pare, e se possivel volte quando o video terminar.

Comment: Qual plugin vc usa pro Carousel?

Comment: Cara to usando o Carousel do Bootstrap com o Pacote do Creative Tim:http://demos.creative-tim.com/get-shit-done/index.html